# Is there a way to create a has_many association that just filters items from another has_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord, has-many

Basically I have a has_many association. I want to create another association that just filters items from the original association.

```rb
class Track
  belongs_to :playlist
end

class Playlist
  has_many :tracks

  has_many :five_start_tracks, -> { what to write here? }
  has_many :long_tracks, -> { ... }
end
```

Is there a way to do it or I should just go with

```rb
def five_star_tracks
  tracks.where(rating: 5)
end
def long_tracks
  tracks.where("duration_seconds > ?", 600)
end
```

Comment: Why create the extra associations?  Just create scopes on the track. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Well I just wanted to keep my methods in the parent class. But if that's not the way of doing things in rails I'm fine with defining scopes too.

Comment: You can do what you wish, but scopes are the railsy approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can [add scopes to `has_many` associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many). But you have to add the class name to the association too, because Ruby on Rails is not able to guess it from the name anymore.

```
class Playlist
  has_many :tracks

  has_many :five_start_tracks, -> { where(rating: 5) }, class_name: 'Track'
  has_many :long_tracks, -> { where('duration_seconds > ?', 600) }, class_name: 'Track'
end
```

Or [`with_options`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-with_options) which might increase readability when you define longer lists of specialized associations:

```
class Playlist
  has_many :tracks

  with_options class_name: 'Track' do
    has_many :five_start_tracks, -> { where(rating: 5) }
    has_many :long_tracks, -> { where('duration_seconds > ?', 600) }
  end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for initially. Thank you! However, I took @dbugger's advice and just declared additional scopes on child class (Track).